# How can I ensure job security and explore new career opportunities given my specialized work?

Tags: job-search

My main concerns revolve around job security and potential salary increases. As an immigrant on an H1B visa, I'm uncertain about my future prospects. I often worry about what will happen if I lose this job or I need to change my job. I'm seeking advice on how to find jobs in very niche fields.

Comment: Will your current employer sponsor a green card? That would be the highest priority before looking at alternate employment.

Comment: Removed morale tags. That isn't what you've asked us to address.

Comment: There is no magic for "very niche fields", especially when we don't know what fields.. Go out and job hunt.

Comment: An H1b visa is not an immigration visa. It is a short-term work permit with an explicit implication of leaving the country after the work is done. If the person loses their job within the 3 year limit (extend to 6), they have 60 days to find another job or leave. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-1B_visa

Comment: My advice: **work hard, extremely hard** so your employer will sponsor you the green card. Then you're okay.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is just to generalize your skills to have more jobs available, it sounds like your best bet might be to either look into editing more generally or technical writing. Both would be natural extensions of what you're doing now. And/or continue the search for a real technical position, though of course the longer you're out of the field the harder it is to get back in except as a writer.

If your question is how to stay in the US, that's something I can't advise on, and that is probably out of scope for Workplace except for the obvious and difficult suggestion to find a sponsor. How one does that, or how one formally immigrates without a sponsor, I have no clue.